# Extraer URL de un string y renderizarlo usando flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Buenas tengo una lista que saco de esta función:

```
def explicacion():
    list = []
    with open('tema1.txt') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
    for a in data:
        list.append(a['prompt']['explanation'])

    return list
```

Y me devuelve algo parecido a esto:

```
['<p>AWS Professional Services shares a collection of offerings to help you achieve specific outcomes related to enterprise cloud adoption. Each offering delivers a set of activities, best practices, and documentation reflecting our experience supporting hundreds of customers in their journey to the AWS Cloud. AWS Professional Services\' offerings use a unique methodology based on Amazon\'s internal best practices to help you complete projects faster and more reliably while accounting for evolving expectations and dynamic team structures along the way.</p><p><br></p><p><img src="https://d1.awsstatic.com/professional-services/Graphics/ProServe%20Method.adec50dd4d04a655d9bb018788ac26238294e3d4.png"></p>
```

¿Cómo puedo renderizar en *flask* la *url* contenida en el *string* de la lista que retorna mi método `explicacion()`?

Comment: ¿ Lo que buscas en renderizar con flask la url dentro el string contenido en la lista ?

Comment: siiii sacar todo ese contenido de la lista en formato html para visualizarlo en html

Answer (score 0):

Podrías extraer la url en tu string con URLExtract pasando el string 

"

AWS Professional Ser..."

 en **<tu_string>**

```
from urlextract import URLExtract

extract = URLExtract()
url_to_render = extract.find_urls(<tu_string>)
```

Luego render_template en flask con tu url. *Ten cuidado que podrías tener mas de una url en el mismo string.*

Comment: Pero eso me extrae las URLs, lo que necesito es todas las etiquetas h1 img ect pasar a formato codigo html para que cuando meta la variable en el body html ya tenga la estrucutra de html.